# php domain mail receiving issue

Tags: php

I am using php mail function its working fine for gmail but when i send it to domain email it show me successful message but not receive on my domain email side where i am wrong. my code is below

```
            <?php
            $to=$_POST['to'];
            $from=abc@gmail.com;
            $name="abc";
            $subject=$_POST['subject'];
            $message=$_POST['message'];
            $headers = 'From:'. $name ."\r\n" . 
            'Reply-To:'. $from . "\r\n" . 
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers,"-f".$from);
            echo "Message sent! <a href='mail.php'>Click here</a> to send another email.";
            ?>
```

my domain email is contact@automailer.netai.net how can i fix this issue,

Comment: that `$from=abc@gmail.com;` needs quotes. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: might be you just have to wait a while for the mail to be delivered too.

Comment: `netai.net` part of the 000webhost network. Don't rely on that server and it's blacklisted on a lot of mailing networks.

Answer (score 0):

There are two completely different processes involved:

- Queueing the mail to your local MTA (This is what PHP's `mail()` does)
- This MTA delivering (with possible hops in between) to the final MTA, which delivers into the users mailbox

Obviously PHP only knows about the first step and may be right to consider it successfully done even if something else later goes wrong - e.g. the receiver domain simply not accepting your mail (which sadly is the new normal).

Answer (score 0):

most likely automailer.netai.net is blacklisted and that's why you aren't getting emails.

try using phpMailer library which is free or popular smtp api that offer free trial as long yo don't pass 10,000 emails per month from

[sendgrid.com](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/php.html),

[maildrill](https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#pricing-features-overview), etc